# System of Equations Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

For part a), I found the eigenvalues to be -7 and +7. I used that to find the eigenvectors and found the general solution to be $[y_1,y_2]=c_1[1,3]e^{(-7t)} +c_2[-2,1]e^{(7t)}$ Is my answer correct or did I make a small error somewhere? I know my process is correct.

I need help with part b). I took the limit as t goes to infinity and notice that the left term would approach 0 while the right term would go to infinity. Could someone help me with this part?

For part c, I just plugged in the vector $[8,3]$ and solved for the constants. I got $c_1=2$ and $c_2=-3$? Is this answer correct? I'm pretty sure I'm correct, I'd just like to be sure.

Comment: Would you know how to solve part b)?

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions for (a) and (c) look fine. For part (b):
Since the solution is decaying to zero $\implies c_2$  must be zero. Then
$y_1 = c_1 e^{-7t}$ and $y_2 = 3 c_1 e^{-7t}$.
$$ \implies \frac{y_1(0)}{y_2(0)} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: Where does the $\frac{1}{3}$ come from?

Comment: Please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

for part (b), your initial condition cannot have any component in the direction of the eigenvector $(-2, 1)^T$ corresponding to the positive eigenvalue. that means $(y_1(0), y_2(0))$ must be a scalar multiple of $(1,3)^T;$ eigenvector corresponding to the negative eigenvalue. that is $$\frac{y_(0)}{y_2(0)} = \frac{1}{3} .$$